# How to refresh the number of items in ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am experimenting with Xamarin (Android) and Visual Studio 2015, I would like to show the list of items (string) loaded into the ListView.

I would like to allow a user to filter the items out and show how many left. Each time a user type a letter the number should be refreshed. Currently the number changes but the value is matching not the last entry but for the one entry before.

Please find the snipped of the code below:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private static readonly List<string> fullData = new List<string>();
    private ListView _dList;
    private EditText _filterText;
    private TextView _numberOfItems;
    private ArrayAdapter<string> _adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("dictionary.txt", Access.Streaming));
        fullData.AddRange(sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None));

        _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, fullData);

        _dList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.dictionaryList);
        _dList.Adapter = _adapter;

        _filterText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.filterText);
        _filterText.TextChanged += FilterOnTextChanged;

        _numberOfItems = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.numberOfItems);
        _numberOfItems.Enabled = false;
        _numberOfItems.Text = string.Format("No. matched: {0}", _dList.Count);
    }

    private void FilterOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(_filterText.Text);
        _numberOfItems.Text = string.Format("No. matched: {0}", _dList.Count);
    }
}
```

Regards,
jbk

Answer (score 1):

Call `_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()` to trigger a refresh:

```
    _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(_filterText.Text);
    _numberOfItems.Text = string.Format("No. matched: {0}", _dList.Count);

    // Notify any dependent views that the underlying data has changed
    _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

See the [BaseAdapter - NotifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) docs

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.